# Get value out of a tailing closure to global variable in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, closures, healthkit

I'm still new to Swift so I feel this question could be very simple, I'm using HKSampleQuery and inside the tailing closure I get a Date value that I want to use outside, the value inside is printed fine but I cant return the value as the HKSampleQuery is declared void function, but I dont know why i cant assign to global variable like value is destroyed after that closure

```
let sleepQuery = HKSampleQuery(
        sampleType: HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis)!,
        predicate: predicate,
        limit: 0,
        sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor])
    {
        (query, results, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil
        {
            return
        }
        myGlobalVariable=CertainDate
        //here value in global variable is correct
    }
print(myGlobalVariable)
//here value in global variable is wrong like it was never assigned, same is seen in 
//global scope
```

I tried changing the return type of the function but I get the environment is void and is not expecting other type to be returned, also tried returning from inside the closure but I got error saying a value was escaping a closude, also tried assigning to a global variabl and didnt work. Tried also making a local variable in the funciton where this query is made and assigning the value to that and later returning it to main code but didnt work like the value is not prevalent out of the closure

Making the return type different is not allowed and so returning the value will not work, same for assigning it to global variable

```
    let sleepQuery = HKSampleQuery(
            sampleType: HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis)!,
            predicate: predicate,
            limit: 0,
            sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) ->Date
```

Comment: Please read this: http://www.programmingios.net/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code/

Comment: You can’t expect an asynchronous method to return a value before it finishes

Comment: Take a look at Swift async await feature or use a completion handler

Comment: Thank you very much, I didnt know this was the issue, Im on my way to making it right now, thanks a lot, should I mark as correct? I dont see the option for that, sorry Im still new to site